# In image segmentation Jaccard index greater than Dice coefficient

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am using unet model for segmentation here I get Jaccard index greater than Dice coefficient is there any problem or it is OK? Can any one explain this?

Comment: when i see the research paper the jaccard index is less than dice but in my case got jaccard index almost 99% and dice 91%  this is why i am confuse.

Answer (score 7):

The [Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient#Formula) is defined as:

```
Dice = 2*TP / ( 2*TP + FP + FN )
```

The [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index#Similarity_of_asymmetric_binary_attributes) is defined as:

```
Jaccard = TP / ( TP + FP + FN )
```

In these equations, `TP` refers to the true positive count (or fraction), and `FP` and `FN` to the false positive and false negative counts (or fractions) respectively. As you can see, the true negatives are not considered in either of these measures.

When `TP` is 0, both measures are 0. When `FP + FN` are 0, both measures are 1. However, for other situations the Dice coefficient is always larger than the Jaccard index. In particular, when `TP == FP + FN`, the situation where the two measures differ most, Dice is 2/3 and Jaccard is 1/2.

The following plot shows the two measures, plots as `TP` vs `FP + TN`. The blue surface is the Dice coefficient, the yellow surface is the Jaccard index.

[image: Plot showing Dice always equal or larger than Jaccard]

Therefore, if your computation of Dice and Jaccard measures lead to a reverse relationship, your computation is wrong. You might want to double-check your code.